# mysqld.exe high disk read

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have no idea why the process is having this kind of activity. The only thing I've done was to insert a couple thousand tables into the database. And inserting like thousand rows each table.

I was using the connector for python yet I've interrupted the kernel already. But the read is still high yet there's no write. Is the process doing anything at all? If not can I just stop the service?

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx...)
```

[image]

---------------------------------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------------------------------

After some time (about 40mins) it started to write for few seconds then it doesn't use the disk anymore.

[image]

Comment: ___insert a couple thousand tables___ ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly: and `And inserting like thousand rows each table.` ... 

Comment: The problem is that it's uses very high read usage after the insert is already done :(
Even if I am inserting why wouldn't it have any writes usage? It should be writing all the time imo.